# Can someone show me how to use HTML or other coding for links?

Tags: support, markdown, posting

I had a perfectly reasonable request that I create a link with words instead of a 'bare link'. Another person gave me an example, but I don't understand it and should not ask that in comments. Could someone help me? I would prefer an example with step by step instructions as I am not particularly savvy.

if what I have here works, I can do this (like a stupid pet trick).

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?newreg=48251eb69f774f069cf3f85f3dc5a7e2' target='_new'>question

Sorry but using words like Markdown only works for a person with some understanding -- this is why the question is *not a duplicate for me*.

Comment: and it didn't.   This was where I had the problem http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64314/what-was-the-last-episode-movie-majel-barrett-recorded/64317#64317

Comment: It's all explained in the [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: okay thanks. Markdown is not a term I've ever heard or used before and I would not know where to find Markdown help -- so I copied/pasted the link Cai supplied. Just so you understand, it took me half an hour to find the chat link. I am not at all savvy about this site and so have to ask questions at that level of understanding. I do appreciate all the help though.

Comment: There is a little "?" button in the post editor and a "help" button next to comment fields that both give a brief explanation and link to that help page :)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. Same answer you got here is given in there.

Comment: thanks again Cai. I never noticed the help button before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is not to use HTML, but Markdown:

```
[the title of the link](http://the.website.com/you-want-to-link-to)
```

This will result in

> [the title of the link](http://the.website.com/you-want-to-link-to)

HTML works as well, but is more complicated:

```
<a href="http://the.website.com/you-want-to-link-to">the title of the link</a>
```

results in

> [the title of the link](http://the.website.com/you-want-to-link-to)

Comment: [my friend's great photos](http://www.pbase.com/northstar37) retest

Comment: I think that worked -- at least it does for me. Can you follow the link?

Comment: Yes, it works .